# What do Titanians drink instead of alcohol?

Tags: moons, biochemistry, food

It is the year 274 After Singularity (2384 AD) Humans have settled on Saturn’s moon Titan and are adapting humans to the methane-rich environment through pantropy. The results are the Titanians: beings that drink liquid methane, breathe hydrogen and breathe out methane vapour, and use acetylene instead of glucose.

But after a hard day at the ice-forge, these Titanians might want to knock off for a pint or two at the local pub. So, given the biochemistry described above, what substitute to alcohol would these beings drink?

Presumably it is produced by the titanian equivalent of a yeast, which ferments acetylene in hydrogen-poor environments just like earthly god-fearing yeasts ferment glucose in anoxic environments, but if Earth yeast produces alcohol, what do titanian yeasts produce?

Comment: Given a completely different physiology, almost anything could be an answer. There is almost no way to distinguish a "right" answer or a "best" answer.

Comment: @DWKraus - user98816 has given us a path to correct,.  OP lays out the equivalent to aerobic metabolism here - reduce acetylene with hydrogen.  The question is really the equivalent of anaerobic metabolism, couched in a scenario that keeps it interesting for readers who are not aficionados of organic chemistry.  Assuming such people exist.

Comment: @DWKraus This is one of the true "worldbuilding" questions (if a difficult one) in that it probably needs chemistry majors to answer it, but they probably would close it on the Chemistry stack for being a fantasy scenario.

Comment: Now THIS is a worldbuilding quesiton: Here's the crazy chemistry of my imaginary world... how can my people get drunk? It's not tagged [tag:science-based], so while we can use science, we can also imagine a new/fanciful biology. Fabulous! +1

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to close or not as I'm not a chemist at all, but seeing the answers, there are good chemistry constraints to scale solutions. To make it clearer directly within your question, perhaps add some basic fluff on your goals at the end. For instance, though I lack clear wording : "My goal is to find a yeast action with cost low-energy chemically, requiring less rare components and producing less byproducts, as following both the principles of chemistry and (indirectly) a biological optimum for this task."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Acetaldehyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetaldehyde)

[image]

1. Made by Acetylene-eating bacteria: [check.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylene#Natural_occurrence)
2. Chemically similar to ethanol:

[image]

check!

3. Similar name to ethanol -- [check.](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=ethanal)
4. Gets Titanians black-out drunk --  check!

Comment: I get starry eyed with those giant molecules.  So moleculey!  But where does the O come from?

Comment: @Willk I have no clue where the O comes from. I answered based on intuition, without checking if the chemistry in the question makes sense to begin with.

Comment: The fact that this molecule is associated with awful hangovers in humans does make it more fun.

Comment: @Willk The oxygen gets in there using the pleasingly named (and chemically elegant) Wacker Process if done artificially. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wacker_process

Comment: This is great. Acetaldehyde gets broken down into acetic acid (vinegar) in the body, so those drunk Titanians have an awful-smelling vinegar breath. Do they do acetaldehyde breathalyzer tests to measure %BAC based on acetic acid content? :-x

Comment: A problem here. Acetaltehyde and methane don't share a temperature to be both liquid. At least not in 1.5 bar pressure on Titan.

Comment: @fraxinus The temperature on Titan would need to be -150 to -175 C for methane to be liquid. Would heating the solid acetaldehyde to temperatures above -123 C (its melting point) turn it into a liquid at Titan's 1.5 bar pressure?

Comment: @TheresaKay melting points don't much depend on pressure. It is the boiling point that travels somewhat, but at 1.5 bar methane won't get enough liquid degrees..

Comment: Is drinking a liquid that solidifies at body temperature a good idea?

Comment: @KevinKostlan On Earth there are many creative ways to overcome our anatomy when taking drugs of all sorts. I am sure the aliens are just as depraved and have many interesting orifices to use.

Comment: @KevinKostlan an oral pill? Why not ingest it as a solid? It will get broken down into acetate in the body either way.

Answer (score 10):

**Benzene**

[image: benzene from acetylene]

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73844/how-is-benzene-prepared-from-acetylene

No additives required.  Just some catalysts and rearrangement of the atoms as a good fermentation should.  And from the answer to the linked question

> Since the aromatic structure of benzene is rather stable compared to
> ethyne, and the product is 1/3 (or 1/4) the number of moles of
> reagents, the formation of product is favored under pressure.

As ethanol is with humans, the proposed metabolism of the Titanians could handle benzene and release energy by hydrogenating it to methane.   But first they DANCE!

Answer (score 3):

Well, methane is too non-polar, too non-protolytic and too non-reactive. I would use ammonia and nitrogen instead.

But since it is your world and not mine:

Ethane or ethene. Both mixable with methane, both can be produced by partial hydrogenation from acetylene, both contain some extra energy that can be extracted by full hydrogenation to methane, but require different mechanisms (enzymes).

If you want to mimic our fermentation without oxygen, your yeast can split the acetylene into ethane/ethene and free carbon (soot that can contaminate the cheap drinks).

If you allow hydrogen into the fermentation container and use a different type of yeast, the result would be a clear drink with no solid contaminants, but the process will be slower and the product will be expensive.

Or a combination thereof.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Give them Titalcohol.

Is there an SE Member who doubts Titalcohol provides exactly the same affects alcohol gives to ordinary humans, and because of its developmental history needs no further explanation?

If you have trouble explaining that much to your audience, readership or viewers, why not explain  that trouble?